# Clients cannot connect to pivpn server anymore

Tags: pi-3, connection, vpn, debug

I have been using and enjoying [pivpn](http://www.pivpn.io/) for nearly a year now. I am running [pivpn](http://www.pivpn.io/) and [Pi-hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-hole) on the same RasPi without issues until now. Recently I have not changed anything besides the occasional `apt update&upgrade`. But now my devices cannot connect to the VPN. They do seem to reach it, as the IP address resolves and the client briefly shows in `pivpn -c` output, if I get the timing right. Below are outputs of `pivpn -c` and `-d` and also output of OpenVPN windows client.

How it looks when I try to connect. I see the connection briefly appear, then disappear. The client never says it's connected.

```
$ pivpn -c

: NOTE : The output below is NOT real-time!
:      : It may be off by a few minutes.

::: Client Status List :::
Bytes           Bytes    Name                    Remote IP               Virtual IP      Received        Sent            Connected Since
numfmt: invalid number: ‘Fri’ UNDEF           CLIENT_IP:36868       556     3.8KiB          6               13:30:08 1530883808 2018 -
```

Debug output from `pivpn -d`

```
::: Generating Debug Output
:::                                     :::
::              PiVPN Debug              ::
:::                                     :::
::      Latest Commit                    ::
:::                                     :::
commit 72b3dc24e7959e61e0233f2fde278bfc6498c114
Merge: 041d410 4e814fc
Author: redfast00 <redfast00@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 22 12:51:48 2017 +0100

Merge pull request #432 from pivpn/cfcolaco-Patch

    Updated Issue Template
:::                                     :::
::      Recursive list of files in       ::
::      /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki        ::
:::                                     :::
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/:
ca.crt
crl.pem
cert1.ovpn
Default.txt
dh4096.pem
cert2.ovpn
index.txt
index.txt.attr
index.txt.attr.old
index.txt.old
issued
cert3.ovpn
private
serial
serial.old
ta.key

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued:
cert1.crt
cert2.crt
cert3.crt
server_F7d0wIVWQ6JYr0Sw.crt

/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private:
ca.key
cert1.key
cert2.key
cert3.key
server_F7d0wIVWQ6JYr0Sw.key
:::                                     :::
::      Output of /etc/pivpn/*           ::
:::                                     :::
:: START /etc/pivpn/DET_PLATFORM ::
Raspbian
:: END /etc/pivpn/DET_PLATFORM ::
:: START /etc/pivpn/INSTALL_PORT ::
1194
:: END /etc/pivpn/INSTALL_PORT ::
:: START /etc/pivpn/INSTALL_PROTO ::
udp
:: END /etc/pivpn/INSTALL_PROTO ::
:: START /etc/pivpn/INSTALL_USER ::
user
:: END /etc/pivpn/INSTALL_USER ::
:: START /etc/pivpn/NO_UFW ::
1
:: END /etc/pivpn/NO_UFW ::
:: START /etc/pivpn/pivpnINTERFACE ::
eth0
:: END /etc/pivpn/pivpnINTERFACE ::
:::                                     :::
:: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/Default.txt ::
:::                                     :::
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote SERVER_IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_F7d0wIVWQ6JYr0Sw name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 1
:::                                     :::
::      Debug Output Complete            ::
:::                                     :::
:::
::: Debug output completed above.
::: Copy saved to /tmp/debug.txt
:::
```

OPENVPN-Windows-Client output:

```
Fri Jul 06 15:36:00 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)]                                         [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Apr 26 2018
Fri Jul 06 15:36:00 2018 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Fri Jul 06 15:36:00 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018, LZO 2.10
Fri Jul 06 15:36:03 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Jul 06 15:36:03 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]SERVER_IP:1194
Fri Jul 06 15:36:03 2018 UDP link local: (not bound)
Fri Jul 06 15:36:03 2018 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]SERVER_IP:1194
Fri Jul 06 15:37:03 2018 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Fri Jul 06 15:37:03 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Fri Jul 06 15:37:03 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Fri Jul 06 15:37:08 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]SERVER_IP:1194
Fri Jul 06 15:37:08 2018 UDP link local: (not bound)
Fri Jul 06 15:37:08 2018 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]SERVER_IP:1194
```

As I said, to the best of my knowledge, no configurations have changed, and I am also the only one having access to the Pi. Also the router settings haven't changed.

Comment: What is *pivpn*? Cannot find it in the repositories. I see `TLS handshake failed`. Maybe there have some public keys expired?

Comment: I have been having the exact same issue on my RPi - pivpn/openvpn timing out for the last few days, same error about TLS handshake. Updated all packages with apt-get, didn't help. (@Ingo pivpn is from pivpn.io, it's a simple installer/configuration tool for openvpn) Edit: In my case I am not using pihole.

Comment: @cometfish Got it. Thanks, have made a suggestion to link to *pivpn* and *Pi-hole* in the question.

Comment: @Ingo thanks. Also please if you catch any private information I forgot to purge, please tell me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the solution for me - hopefully it helps you too!

Found that /var/log/openvpn.log on the RPi had the line "VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=CRL has expired"
Searching that gave several results saying to regenerate the Certificate Revocation List, but I couldn't find how to do this with pivpn.

Found this workaround and it worked: use pivpn to add a new user, then revoke the user - the revoke output notes that it regenerates the CRL. I was then able to connect again straightaway :)
https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=26585

Comment: Thank you very much that workaround with adding and revoking a new user worked!